# Manhwa/Manghwa where every time the main characters try to commit suicide they exchange bodies

Tags: story-identification, manga

I saw someone recommending it on TikTok but I never got to search it up and I can’t remember the title. The main female character was blonde, there was a black haired guy and also a blonde one dressed as a prince. Apparently every time they try to commit suicide they exchange bodies (the female lead and the black haired guy).

Answer (score 3):

This is likely [What It Means to Be You](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=178545). The theme of suicide and the character descriptions match. The "blonde male prince" is probably the female lead's younger brother, who appears in the first chapter.

[image: Cover]

This is a brand new series so I can't confirm that they switch bodies multiple times, but novel spoilers I read do suggest that the series involves multiple suicides.